# Inequalities on greatest integer function

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For a real number $r$ we denote by $[r]$ the largest integer less than or equal to $r$.If $x,y \geq 1$ ,then which of the following statements is always true.

A)  $[x+y] \leq [x]+[y]$

B)  $[xy] \leq [x][y]$

C)  $[2^x] \leq 2^{[x]}$

D)  $[\frac xy] \leq |\frac xy|$

I tried the options by plugging in different values of x and y and till now I could not find x and y such that A) is incorrect.but that doesn’t guarantee that A) should be the correct option. I could not find out a  pure algebraic proof of the same.please help me in this regard.thanks.

Comment: Try $x=y={3 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat is right, any odd integer divided by 2 breaks that rule. Does the question entail that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In general, a good approach to looking for counterexamples is to try numbers close to the 'edge', such as $1.9,1.99,1.999999999999999999999999999999999999999,...$ ;-).

Comment: @copper.hat can you find out a contradiction to D).

Comment: @dsillman2000 but that is not a contradiction.

Comment: One always has $\lfloor z \rfloor \le z$, and we always have $w \le |w|$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat that's the correct reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $C$ is wrong! Try $x=1.9$.

$A$ is also wrong. Try $x=y=1.6$.

$B$ is also wrong: $x=y=1.5$.

$D$ is true of course.