# A doubt about greatest integer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is a question with reference to a previous post.
[Inequalities on greatest integer function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989442/inequalities-on-greatest-integer-function)

In the question posted there, I understand why the options A, B, D are true or false.
But there is no strong proof that option C, $[2^x] \leq 2^{[x]}$ is true or false.
So can you please explain about that option C.

*In that post only a counterexample is given. I want solid algebraic proof.*

Comment: A counter-example *is* a solid proof for the falseness of a statement.

Comment: @MartinR I want to know it algebraically and logically. To me, psychologically, I do not feel counterexample is strong enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $[x]=k$ then $k \leq x <k+1$ which implies $2^{k } \leq 2^{x} <2^{k+1}$. This implies $l\leq 2^{x} <l+1$ for some $l 
\geq 2^{k}$. Hence $[2^{x}]=l \geq 2^{k}=2^{[x]}$.